# When can assign a function to a var?

Tags: javascript

Why can't I assign a non-nested function to a variable `counter`? Why does the second function generates error?

The first one:

```
function makeCounter() {
  return function() {
    return "hello";
  };
};
let counter = makeCounter();
console.log( counter() );
```

The second:

```
function makeCounter(){
  return "hello";
};
let counter = makeCounter();
console.log( counter() );
```

Comment: You are assigning a string to `counter` in the second example. That is what makeCounter returns.

Comment: You should have done `let counter = makeCounter` without the parentheses. To be closed as "typo/trivial".

Comment: @idmean thanks! so can I understand as -in the first sample counter is assigned to the nested part of the function only? in the second example, why can't i assign counter to a string?

Comment: In each example you are assigning the *return value* of `makeCounter` to a variable. And the obvious difference between the two is that the first one returns a function and  the second one returns a string. To answer the question in the title: Always. A function is a value and you can assign any value to a variable, anytime.

Comment: @FelixKling That's more clear to me now! However, if the second one returns a string, why can't it be assigned to a variable?

Comment: What is “it”? The string is assigned to `counter` just fine. You just cannot *call* it (`counter()`) because a string is not a function. If you do `console.log(counter)` instead you will see that it holds the string value.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the function but a result of its `return` in the second case, which is a string `hello`, change your code to this to work:

```
function makeCounter(){
  return "hello";
};
let counter = makeCounter; // Assign function reference
console.log( counter() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the function as reference then it will work fine.

```js
function makeCounter(){
  return "hello";
};
let counter = makeCounter;
console.log( counter() );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you defining

```
function makeCounter(){
  return "hello";
};
let counter = makeCounter();
console.log( counter() ); `
```

You are defining a function to return a string, not a function.

And at the first function, you are defining a function to return a function, that why you can call it with as a function- you can use `()` here

```
function makeCounter() {
  return function() {
    return "hello";
 };
};
```