# Javascript closure - count invocations

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS closure concept. I'm stuck at the Part 2 of an exercise.

Here's the question:

> Part 1: 
>   Write a statement that, when executed, binds the variable inc
>   to a function that takes a number (x) and returns that number x + 1.
>
> Part 2:
>   Create a new file, counter.js which exports `up` which takes no
>   arguments, and which on its first invocation returns 1; on its second
>   invocation, returns 2; and, in general, on its nth invocation returns
>   n. This function should not use any arithmetic operators directly, but
>   **should use inc.**

My answer to part 1:

```
// inc.js 

function plusOne(x){
    return x+1;
}
module.exports.plusOne = plusOne;
```

My answer to part 2:

```
let inc = require('./inc.js')

function makeCounter(){
    let count = 0;
    return inc.plusOne(count);
};

let counter = makeCounter;

console.log( counter() ); // should execute 0 
console.log( counter() ); // should execute 1 
console.log( counter() ); // should execute 2
```

My answer to part 2 is clearly not right because I got "1" to all 3 prints.

---

I also have an additional question for the same function(I wasn't sure to add it here or add it to the other question i asked)- 
In part 2, changing

```
let counter = makeCounter;
```

to

```
let counter = makeCounter();
```

would generate an error. I posted this as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893237/when-can-assign-a-function-to-a-var). But my answer to part 2, makeCounter() does return a function `inc.plusOne(count)` instead of string. Why is there still an error?

Comment: `makeCounter` should return a function that increments and updates the local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As george commented, your `makeCounter` function should create a closure by returning a function with mutating `count` variable in its closure. That makes `count` to store its value among function calls. It looks like this:

```js
function inc(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  return function callsCounter() {
    count = inc(count);
    return count;
  }
}

const myCounter = makeCounter()

console.log(myCounter())
console.log(myCounter())
console.log(myCounter())
```

On each call of returned function (named `callsCounter` in my case) you need to reassign next value to count variable and return its value.